# Can "printThis" print a table and a div on the same page?

Tags: jquery, html, printthis

I'm using printThis Jquery plugin. I use it to print out a table. But now i want to add a div below the table. Is that possible?

My code prints the table and the div on two seperate papers.

**HTML**

```
<table id="list_usr_time" class="display"></table
<div class="display" id="sum_worked_time"></div>
```

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#print_btn').click(function () {
        $('#list_usr_time').printThis();
        $('#sum_worked_time').printThis();
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The answear was pretty simple! Just edited the JS.

**JS**

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#print_btn').click(function () {
        $('#list_usr_time, #sum_worked_time').printThis();
    });
});
```